# custom alert dialog background color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

i need a custom alert dialog for show progress. when i run it the alert dialog background color not change to transparent...
below i put my code in xml layout and alert dialog code

xml layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

and this is my code in fragment :

```
                View progress = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.progress_alert, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setView(progress);
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Along with the background color, use android:alpha between 0 and 1 to get the preferred transparency

Comment: no my friend its not working

Comment: cardview is white by default. Add alpha to the cardview also. Let me know if that works.

Comment: see photo this my problem and not changing by alpha @AtickFaisal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set dialog theme like this in styles.xml

```
<style name="dialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
</style>
```

java code

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.dialogTheme);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
activity.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: for me this was also needed: 
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.0f);

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of alert dialog to be transparent with:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: no solve my friend can you see the first line of alert codes, can problem related to "null" in this and i should to change?

Answer (score 0):

see you can create xml file for progressBar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutProgressBar"
android:visibility="gone"
android:elevation="8dp"
>

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:theme="@style/RedAccent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And include this layout line in xml file where you want this progressbar like this:

```
<include layout="progressbar" />
```

and access like this:

```
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutProgressBar);
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: exactly what do you want?? you want to hide or dismiss the dialog ?? or something else why do you change its color to transparent it almost like hiding dialog box you want like this??

Comment: yeah i want to hide background and show only progressbar

Comment: i dont think that will work if you gone the visibility of cardview. you should try ProgressBar  refer this video to understand https://youtu.be/YsHHXg1vbcc

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
                                              ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: no i write your code but still with white background

Comment: It works for me, i think you also have to set the parent layout to transparent in xml! 
this is one of the simplest sol i knew, try to set transparent background of parent view in xml and than use this line. It will work , thats how i did it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried all the ways, but what worked for me was to delete AlertDialog and replace it with Dialog

and just do this

```
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```